# How to compare two array and create new one with different key value pair?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two array and need to take specific key value pair and assign to third one array and it will also  take care of duplication entry.

First Array :

```
[ 
  {id: 2, name: "HSBC", status: "YES"},
  {id: 3, name: "Morgan Stanley", status: "Pending"}
]
```

Second Array:

```
[
   {id: 1, name: "Deutsche Bank", category: "EQUITIES"},
   {id: 2, name: "HSBC", category: "EQUITIES"},
   {id: 3, name: "Morgan Stanley", category: "EQUITIES"},
   {id: 4, name: "Credit Suisse", category: "EQUITIES"},
]
```

From above two arrays I need to take name and status field and create the new array. Like below:

```
[
  { brokerName: "HSBC", statis: "YES"},
  { brokerName: "Morgan Stanley", statis: "Pending"},
  { brokerName: "Deutsche Bank", statis: ""},
  { brokerName: "Credit Suisse", statis: ""},
]
```

TIA.
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1f2wbx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr1 = [{id: 1, name: "name", status: "YES"}];
let arr2 = [{id: 1, name: "name", category: "EQUITIES"}];
let sumbit = [];

for (let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
    let is_there = false;
    for (let j=0; j<arr2.length; j++) {
        if (arr1[i].name == arr[j].name) {
            submit.push({brokerName: arr1[i].name, statis: arr1[i].status});
            is_there = true;
        }
    }
    if (!is_there) submit.push({brokerName: arr1[i].name, statis: ""})
}
```

You could just write the code :D

Comment: Thanks for the above solution. I have tried on my provided arrays its not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```js
const array1 = [ 
  {id: 2, name: "HSBC", status: "YES"},
  {id: 3, name: "Morgan Stanley", status: "Pending"}
];
const array2 = [
   {id: 1, name: "Deutsche Bank", category: "EQUITIES"},
   {id: 2, name: "HSBC", category: "EQUITIES"},
   {id: 3, name: "Morgan Stanley", category: "EQUITIES"},
   {id: 4, name: "Credit Suisse", category: "EQUITIES"},
];

// returns { name, status } recoreds from any number of arrays
function getBrokersDataFromArrays(...arrays) {
  const allBrokers = new Map();
  // collect all the available data for all the brokers
  arrays.flat().forEach(broker => {
    if (allBrokers.has(broker.name)) {
      allBrokers.set(broker.name, { ...allBrokers.get(broker.name), ...broker });
    } else {
      allBrokers.set(broker.name, broker);
    }
  });
  // return only { name, status } fields from the collected brokers
  return Array.from(allBrokers.values()).map(broker => (
    { name: broker.name, status: broker.status }
  ));
}

const brokersData = getBrokersDataFromArrays(array1, array2);

console.log(brokersData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array1 = [ 
    {id: 2, name: "HSBC", status: "YES"},
    {id: 3, name: "Morgan Stanley", status: "Pending"}
  ]

let array2 = [
    {id: 1, name: "Deutsche Bank", category: "EQUITIES"},
    {id: 2, name: "HSBC", category: "EQUITIES"},
    {id: 3, name: "Morgan Stanley", category: "EQUITIES"},
    {id: 4, name: "Credit Suisse", category: "EQUITIES"},
 ]
   
 // filter data which are present into both array
    const result1 = array1.filter(o => array2.some(({ name }) => o.name === name));
    
    // filter data which are present into array1 but not into array2
    const result2 = array1.filter((o1) => {
        return !array2.some((o2) => {
            return o1.name === o2.name;
        });
    })
    
    // filter data which are present into array2 but not into array1
    const result3 = array2.filter((o1) => {
        return !array1.some((o2) => {
            return o1.name === o2.name;
        });
    })
    
    // concat all result
    let result = (result1.concat(result2)).concat(result3)
    
    let finalArr = []
    for (let obj of result) {
        finalArr.push({ brokerName: obj.name, status: obj.status ? obj.status : "" })
    }
```